# ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional

Tags: python, numpy

I have following codes to plot a gassian-2d contour,but I get this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "question.py", line 15, in <module>
    Z0=gaussian_2d(X0,Y0,2,3,cov)
  File "question.py", line 4, in gaussian_2d
    return exp(-0.5*mat([x-x0,y-y0])*sigmaMatrix.I*mat([x-x0,y-y0]).T)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 96, in asmatrix
    return matrix(data, dtype=dtype, copy=False)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 272, in __new__
    raise ValueError("matrix must be 2-dimensional")
ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional
```

This my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
def gaussian_2d(x, y, x0, y0, sigmaMatrix):
    return exp(-0.5*mat([x-x0,y-y0])*sigmaMatrix.I*mat([x-x0,y-y0]).T)
cov=mat([[1,0],[0,2]])
delta=0.025
xgrid=arange(-2, 6, delta)
ygrid=arange(-2, 6, delta)
X0, Y0 = meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid)
Z0=gaussian_2d(X0,Y0,2,3,cov)
```

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Look at `np.mat([X0, Y0])`.  That is, in effect, what you are trying to do in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Error starts from the concatenation but also your matrix dimensions don't match.

You are performing a quadratic form multiplication `x^T A x` but your `meshgrid` variables are square matrices of 320x320. Your A matrix `cov` is 2x2 hence you get an error.

If the sizes matches you can column concatenate `mat(c_[x-x0,y-y0])` or use any other stacking option.